# Change text field to grayed out with condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Im using the following code which is created via MVC5 application and I've field called Type which is drop down list,what I need is that user and password box will be grayed out when you change to Prod currently by defult its Dev(the drop down list field - Type ) the user and passowrd field change to enabled ,how should I do that ?

```
public class Ad
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

public string User { get; set; }

public string Password { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Type
{
get
{
return new[]
{
new SelectListItem {Value = "D", Text = "Dev"},
new SelectListItem {Value = "p", Text = "Production"}
};
}
}
```

The create generated code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Admin</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, Model.Type)

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**THe updated code with the script**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('select[name="Type"]').change(function () {

        if ($(this).val() === 'Production')
        {

            $('input[name="User"]').prop("disabled",true);
            $('input[name="Password"]').prop("disabled",true);
        }

        else
        {
            $('input[name="User"]').prop("disabled",false);
            $('input[name="Password"]').prop("disabled",false);
        }

    });
</script>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Admin</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, Model.Type)

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it using jquery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('select[name="Type"]').change(function(){

    if($(this).val() === 'prod')
    {

        $('input[name="User"]').prop("disabled",true);
        $('input[name="Password"]').prop("disabled",true);
    }

        else
        {
        $('input[name="User"]').prop("disabled",false);
        $('input[name="Password"]').prop("disabled",false);
        }

    });
});

</script>
```

Here is [**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mr379/)

Comment: thank you very much,where should I put this code?can you please add it to the code which I posted,Im very new to this topic...,Thanks in advance!

Comment: include it at the top of the view before Html.BeginForm

Comment: also make sure to include Jquery script file in your main layout

Comment: I've add it in the create file ,do I need to add some tag for it? what do you mean by Jquery script file?

Comment: yes add it in this tag:
<script type="text/javascript"> </script> and put jquery code inside this

Comment: jquery script file its by default included in asp.net mvc project see in your solution explorer Scripts folder

Comment: I've added the tag and put it like you said and its not working...what  about the Jquery script file? Btw I run the fiddele and this is exactly what I need ...

Comment: include like this if its in Scripts Folder: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")"></script>

Comment: I've edit the post and add the code...can you please check what is missing?

Comment: Thanks but still not working ,did you put it on razor file ?since maybe I need to add addtional referance or someting ...

Comment: currenlty its not working I think that we are missing sometning that this is not working,I mark it as solved since I guess your code should  work ...I'll open new question...THanks!

Comment: Yes it to be put in razor file,  you are doing some other thing wrong otherwise it should work

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
$('#dropDownElement').change(function(){

    if($(this).text() == "Production")
    {
       $('#passwordElement').prop('readonly',true);
       $('#userElement').prop('readonly',true);
    } 
    else
    {
       $('#passwordElement').prop('readonly',false);
       $('#userElement').prop('readonly',false);   
    }

 })
```

If `prop('readonly',true);` will not work, try `attr('disabled', 'disabled');`